# Find keystore of an apk file

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I uploaded an android application a few months ago and I will need to upload version-3 soon. But I forgot which key-store file I used to sign the previous APK.
Therefore, how do I check which key-store file I used to sign the APK file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several keystores with you then you can try making apks with them try uploading the APKs.

If it accepts then you are lucky. This is the original keystone you used while signing the first time.

If you don't have the original keystore then it is not possible as per my knowledge.